# Are LinkedBlockingQueue's insert and remove methods thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

I'm using `LinkedBlockingQueue` between two different threads. One thread adds data via `add`, while the other thread receives data via `take`.

My question is, do I need to synchronize access to `add` and `take`. Is `LinkedBlockingQueue`'s insert and remove methods thread safe?

Comment: If they weren't thread safe, then you'd need to synchronize it. Then a take() might very well grab the mutex of an empty queue, blocking any other thread from adding to it. Hello deadlock!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Yes.   From [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html):

> "BlockingQueue implementations are
>   thread-safe. All queuing methods
>   achieve their effects atomically using
>   internal locks or other forms of
>   concurrency control. However, the bulk
>   Collection operations addAll,
>   containsAll, retainAll and removeAll
>   are not necessarily performed
>   atomically unless specified otherwise
>   in an implementation. So it is
>   possible, for example, for addAll(c)
>   to fail (throwing an exception) after
>   adding only some of the elements in
>   c."

Comment: isnt it actually. No, not if you are just using add and take, but if you would use a bulk operation you would have to synchronize it instead of just plain "Yes"? Or am i reading the doc wrong?

Comment: @cproinger, no, you never have to synchronize it, as long as you're willing to deal with `addAll` throwing an exception after adding a subset of the items (or similar).  It depends how you define thread-safe.  You're right that the bulk methods don't have an atomicity guarantee.

Comment: "So it is possible, for example, for addAll(c) to fail (throwing an exception) after adding only some of the elements in c." isn't this a "no"?

Answer (score 17):

Yes, `BlockingQueue` methods `add()` and `take()` are thread safe **but with a difference**.

`add ()` and `take()` method uses 2 different `ReentrantLock` objects.

`add(`) method uses

```
private final ReentrantLock putLock = new ReentrantLock();
```

`take()` method uses

```
private final ReentrantLock takeLock = new ReentrantLock();
```

Hence, simultaneous access to `add()` method is synchronized. Similarly, simultaneous access to `take()` method is `synchronized`.

**But, simultaneous access to `add()` and `take()` method is not `synchronized` since they are using 2 different lock objects (except during edge condition of queue full / empty).**

Comment: This answer makes a valid observation, but misses that the implementers of LinkedBlockingQueue were aware of this problem and addressed it.  Details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543807/is-blockingqueue-completely-thread-safe-in-java/26543940#26543940

Comment: Yes , i agree. LInkedBlockingQueue offers betters concurrency than ArrayBlockingQueue and maintains thread safety by synchronizing edge condition only. Insert and remove methods have been smartly synchronized for edge cases only

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  `add` and `take` are thread-safe and can be used concurrently without extra synchronization.

Comment: Corrected my answer. Simultaneous add and take are not synchronized except during edge condition of queue full / empty.

Comment: I think the answer is confusing. I think even when they are not synchronized, they are still safe and there is no need to synchronize manually.

Comment: yes, no need to synchronise manually since the implementation provides for it. Implementation is smart enough to synchronise add with remove and vice versa only when queue is empty / full. Check implementation of this in the source code. This will be become more clear

Comment: The worrying part of a single lock for `add()` is that many threads could be slowed down when inserting at the same time since add()'s should go through serially.

Answer (score -1):

Simply Yes, its definitely thread safe otherwise it wouldn't have qualified as a candidate for storing element for **ThreadPoolExecutor**.

Simply add and retrieve element without worrying about concurrency for BlockingQueue.

Comment: It's just advertised as thread-safe, in reality docs read "So it is possible, for example, for addAll(c) to fail (throwing an exception) after adding only some of the elements in c. "