# What would happen if putting and taking simultaneously when Java LinkedBlocking Queue only has one element?

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

LinkedBlocking Queue has two locks, one for putting, one for taking. When the size of the queue is 1, I think two threads can lock and manipulate the queue simultaneously, which will cause undefined behavior. Am I wrong?

```
// method put:                             // method take:             
// put lock                                // take lock
 putLocK.lockInterruptibly();              takeLock.lockInterruptibly();                      
 ...                                       ...

 while(count.get() == capacity){           while(count.get() == 0){
   notFull.await();                          notEmpty.await();
 }                                         }
 enqueue(node);                            x = dequeue();

// method enqueue:                         // method dequeue:
  last = last.next = node;                 Node<E> h = head;    
 ...                                       Node<E> first = h.next;
                                           h.next = h;        
                                           head = first;     
                                           E x = first.item;     
                                           first.item = null;   
                                           return x;
```

Clearly put thread and take thread can lock when there's only one item in queue, therefore they will execute codes in method enqueue and dequeue respectively. I mean if take thread enters method dequeue, after all that pointer modification, doesn't collide with the codes in enqueue?

Links here says "However when the queue is empty then the contention cannot be avoided, and so extra code is required to handle this common 'edge' case"

[Is BlockingQueue completely thread safe in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543807/is-blockingqueue-completely-thread-safe-in-java/26543940#26543940)

Comment: FYI: There is no "simultaneously" when you're talking about shared objects and a conventional multi-processor computer system. In order for threads to communicate via shared objects, they must read and write locations in the system's main memory. A conventional system has only one memory bus, and every read and every write must go over that bus in single-file. A big part of understanding multi-processor problems is understanding and anticipating the different ways in which read and write requests can be _serialized_ by the hardware when threads _attempt_ to use the bus at the same time.

Comment: *I think two threads can lock and manipulate the queue simultaneously...* No. The whole point of locking is that two threads can't lock simultaneously.

Comment: @shmosel Two threads, two different lock. One modifies the head, one modifies the tail. LinkedBlockingQueue is designed for putting and taking at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

`put` implementation of a `LinkedBlockingQueue`

```java
public void put(E e) throws InterruptedException {
    // some lock and node code

    // the part that matters here
    try {

        while (count.get() == capacity) {
            notFull.await();
        }

        // put the item in the queue.
    } finally {
        // not important here
    }
}
```

Basically, in `put`, the calling thread `wait`s for the capacity to be less than the max continuing.

Even though the thread putting the value on the queue grabs a lock that is different from the take thread, it waits to add it to the queue until the queue is not full.

`take` has a similar implementation with regards to `notEmpty` instead of `notFull`.

Comment: What Ivan says is wrong, LinkedBlockingQueue does have two locks. I just wanna know how can it be thread-safe when size is 1.

Comment: If they respectively grab their own lock, which is "putLock" and "takeLock". In theory, the two threads can put and take the only element at the same time. BUT in practice, no, why?

Comment: It cannot happen at the same time because `take` can't _take_ unless there __is__ an item in the queue, and `put` can't _put_ unless there are __no__ items in the queue. In the case of the size being 1, one of the two can't do anything until the other happens, which is why it is safe

Comment: @asapdiablo I added some edits to my answer to help clarify better.

Comment: If put only happens in queue empty, then thread safe can be guaranteed.

Comment: You are correct. Again, this is assuming the queue size is 1.

Comment: no! Put can happen when queue is not empty.  If put can't happen then the throughput of queue will be very low. So there's another reason why is thread safe.

Comment: By `put` can happen, I am assuming you mean you can call `put` when the queue is not empty. This is true. But it will then block the calling thread and wait until the queue is empty before it puts the element in.

Comment: In the source code, the put thread will block only if "count == capacity". Then assume there's one item in the queue, and capacity is 5, now take and put can both get their locks. If my opinion is true, then how does the queue guarantees thread safe?

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) for BlockingQueue (the superclass of LinkedBlockingQueue) states this:

> `BlockingQueue` implementations are thread-safe. **All queuing methods achieve their effects atomically** using internal locks or other forms of concurrency control.

The word "atomically" means that if two operations (for example a `put` and a `take`) happen simultaneously, then the implementation will ensure that they behave according to the contract.  The effect will be *as if* the `put` happens before `get` or vice-versa.  That applies to edge-cases as well, such as your example of a queue with one element.

In fact, since `put` and `get` are blocking operations, the relative ordering of the two operations won't matter.  With `offer` / `poll` or `add` / `remove` the order *does* matter, but you can't control it.

---

Please note that the above is based solely on what the javadoc says.  Assuming that I have interpreted the javadoc correctly, then it applies to all<sup>1</sup> `BlockingQueue` implementations, irrespective of whether they use one or two locks ... or none at all.  If a `BlockingQueue` implementation doesn't behave as above, that is a bug!

<sup>1 - All implementations that implement the API correctly.  That should cover all of the Java SE classes.</sup>

Comment: The doc itself only defines the behavior, I just wanna know how the implementation guarantees thread-safe when size = 1.

Comment: "I just wanna know how the implementation guarantees thread-safe when size = 1." - It is thread-safe.  The javadoc says so, and if there was an implementation bug that caused it to not be thread-safe, it would have been found *years ago*.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of search, I finally get it...
When the queue has only one item, according to LinkedBlocking Queue's design, there are actually two nodes: the dummy head and really item(meanwhile last points to it). It's true that put thread and take thread can both get their lock, but they modify different parts of the queue.

Put thread will call

```
last = last.next = node; // last points to the only item in queue
```

Take thread will call

```
Node<E> h = head;
Node<E> first = h.next;  // first also points to the only item in queue
h.next = h; 
head = first;
E x = first.item;
first.item = null;
return x;
```

The intersection of these two threads is what last points to in put thread and what first points to in take thread. 
Notice that put thread only modifies last.item and take thread only modifies first.next. Although these two threads modifies the same object instance, **they modifies the different member of it, and it won't bring about any thread conflicts.**