# Do I need to use "synchronized" keyword to get/add if using java.util.concurrent data structure?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, thread-safety

My code has a data structure shared between many threads, but I am using `LinkedBlockingQueue`, so would **synchronized** be necessary at all in the following code?

```
public synchronized String getDirectory(){
    return directoryArray.poll();
}
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695426/are-linkedblockingqueues-insert-and-remove-methods-thread-safe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think you required extra synchronization. According to docs - [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

> BlockingQueue implementations are
>   thread-safe. All queuing methods
>   achieve their effects atomically using
>   internal locks or other forms of
>   concurrency control. However, the bulk
>   Collection operations addAll,
>   containsAll, retainAll and removeAll
>   are not necessarily performed
>   atomically unless specified otherwise
>   in an implementation. So it is
>   possible, for example, for addAll(c)
>   to fail (throwing an exception) after
>   adding only some of the elements in
>   c.

Answer (score 3):

No, it will just slow down your application without any benefits. Implementation of `LinkedBlockingQueue#poll()` has already implemented synchronization mechanism using a reentrant lock:

```
public E poll() {
    final AtomicInteger count = this.count;
    if (count.get() == 0)
        return null;
    E x = null;
    int c = -1;
    final ReentrantLock takeLock = this.takeLock;
    takeLock.lock();
    try {
        if (count.get() > 0) {
            x = dequeue();
            c = count.getAndDecrement();
            if (c > 1)
                notEmpty.signal();
        }
    } finally {
        takeLock.unlock();
    }
    if (c == capacity)
        signalNotFull();
    return x;
}
```

Comment: The implementation might change - you should refer to the contract of the class, defined in the javadoc.

Comment: Agree that it can be changed, but sometimes people, especially if English is not their mother tongue believe more in the source code than javadoc.

Answer (score 2):

Since `LinkedBlockingQueue` implements `BlockingQueue`, this [documented behavior](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) applies to it:

> `BlockingQueue` implementations are thread-safe. All queuing methods achieve their effects atomically using internal locks or other forms of concurrency control.

This means that no additional synchronization is necessary.