# Is there a synchronized queue in Java?

Tags: java, synchronized

Is there a synchronized `Queue` class in Java? I'm looking for something like `Vector` (which is synchronized) vs `ArrayList` (which is not), but instead of implementing the `List` interface, I'm looking for it to implement `Queue`.

Note that there is no `Collections.synchronizedQueue` method to wrap an unsynchronized queue and make it synchronized.

Comment: ConcurrentLinkedDeque

Comment: If you look through the docs of the classes that extend https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractQueue.html you'll probably find what you're looking for.  And https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695426/are-linkedblockingqueues-insert-and-remove-methods-thread-safe

Comment: This seems like a very valid question, since Queue seems to be different from other Java collections in this respect. I am going to request that it is re-opened, having edited to clarify the question a little.

Answer (score 6):

Look at [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) and another [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) implementations.

From documentation:

> A Queue that additionally supports operations that wait for the queue to become non-empty when retrieving an element, and wait for space to become available in the queue when storing an element.

Comment: This is a blocking queue, which is not what was requested.

Comment: @rghome I believe OP wanted to find thread-safe implementation, in this case my answer is correct

Comment: I was concerned about the blocking behaviour. If the reader/writer blocks, then this is very different behaviour than in a standard non-blocking queue. But reading the API, I think this is optional and you can read/write non-blocking as well. So you are correct.

Comment: It is possible to avoid blocking, but ArrayBlockingQueue has a fixed capacity.

Comment: This answer is missing the point: `BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe.` [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'BlockingQueue', below link may help you to get better idea about it

[BlockingQueue](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/blocking-queues.html),
[Queue Implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/queue.html)

Answer (score -2):

How about SynchronousQueue?
Refer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html

Comment: that's a very specialized implementation, not really general use.