# Is there a way to communicate between two completely independent threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, javaagents

I am trying to communicate between two threads which do not share any object in Java (I am building a Java agent). What I need is something like the following :

```
Thread agentattachThread = ...;
otherThread.send("Hello");
```

And this would be handled like an interrupt in the Agent Attach thread, like so :

```
public void msgHandler(String msg) {
    ...
}

Thread.onMessageReceived(msgHandler);
```

**EDIT** - Considering the answers to my original post, my question becomes : does the JVM offer by default a synchronized object to which all threads could get a reference to ?

Comment: The only way to communicate between threads is by using synchronized objects

Comment: And those are either shared within java or you leverage e.g. the file system as a synchronization point, e.g. pipes.

Comment: Of course  there are alot of ways. But which is the best you should decide.

Comment: Does such an object exist by default ? Like is there an instance of a SynchronizedQueue which all threads could get a reference to ?

Comment: @AntoineG Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460793/is-there-a-synchronized-queue-in-java)

Comment: Sorry, I misformulated my question. Let me reformulate : is there an instance of such an object, created at startup by the JVM and to which all running threads could easily grab a reference to ?

Comment: @AntoineG Clarify your Question by editing the Question, not posting Comments.

Comment: Is defining your own static object in some class under your control (e.g. one of the classes used in the implementation of the agent) to synchronize on not an option?

Comment: @SaatvikRamani You can also use concurrent collections which don't use synchronization.

Comment: @nanofarad this I can do, and that is where I am heading at the moment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to "communicate" from thread to thread *without sharing some object* is via [`Thread.interrupt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--) Obviously, the only signal you can send by this means is a `true` flag, and the receiver will only notice it when it uses certain methods, like [`Thread.interrupted()`,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted--) or a method that raises `InterruptedException`.

Because this is so limited, it's standard practice to share a thread-safe object between threads which offers the interface needed by the application. For example, you could give each thread a reference to the same [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) and send messages that way.

Any public, static field is globally visible, so a shared object such as a queue could be accessed via such a field by any thread.

The closest thing to that "built-in" to the JVM that comes to mind are system properties; essentially, this is a shared map via which any thread can set or get `String`-type entries. There might be some other facilities that could be abused in a similar way, but I can't imagine any reason to use something like this when a static field would serve.

Comment: Thinking aloud: The static field works, as long as you can rely on a class being loaded by only a single class loader. With even the simplest class loader isolation scenario, this would no longer work VM-wide, because you would have one static field per loaded class. But other than in this specific case, the suggested solution is great.

Answer (score 1):

There are some choices I found.

1. NIO pipe.
2. socket.
3. a global synchronized object.
4. signal.

I think signal and callback machanism are what you need. You have to implement it by yourself or use thirdparty tool.

Comment: I finally used a synchronized object, declared as a public static attribute of an already defined class

Answer (score 1):

You asked in your title:

> Is there a way to communicate between two completely independent threads?

(a) Threads within a JVM are never “completely independent”, in that threads share the resources and constraints of the JVM.

(b) Yes, there are many ways for objects to communicate, both within a thread or across threads.

You asked in your comment:

> is there an instance of such an object, created at startup by the JVM and to which all running threads could easily grab a reference to ?

Threads don't grab references to objects, the objects executing methods within a thread grab references.

There are many objects available when a JVM launches. For example, [`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#out). Any object executing in any thread can access such objects.

Frameworks provide additional objects to be shared across threads. For example, the [Jakarta Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Servlet) framework provides an instance of `ServletContext` representing the web app for use across all the threads processing requests.

But probably the solution you need is quite simple: **Pass the objects needed.** When instantiating the `Runnable` or `Callable` object to be executed within a thread, pass needed resources to the constructor. Instead of thinking in terms of "grabbing" a global object, think of "being handed" needed objects.

In this example, we create two instances of our `Runnable` class `Counter`, `Runnable task1` and `Runnable task2`. For each instance, we pass a shared resource, an `AtomicInteger` instance. The `Atomic…` means the object is internally [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety), so we can safely manipulate the single instance across threads.

```java
package work.basil.threading;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class App {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo () {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool( 3 );
        AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger( 0 );  // Shared object.
        Runnable task1 = new Counter( count );  // ⟸ Pass shared object to constructor of each `Runnable`/`Callable`. 
        Runnable task2 = new Counter( count );
        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate( task1 , 0 , 5 , TimeUnit.SECONDS );
        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate( task2 , 0 , 7 , TimeUnit.SECONDS );

        try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 40 ).toMillis() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
        try { scheduledExecutorService.awaitTermination( 5 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        System.out.println( "count = " + count );
    }

    class Counter implements Runnable {
        AtomicInteger countingTracker;

        public Counter ( AtomicInteger countingTracker ) {
            this.countingTracker = countingTracker;
        }

        @Override
        public void run () {
            Instant instant = Instant.now();
            int currentCount = this.countingTracker.incrementAndGet();
            System.out.println( "`Counter` object in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " set this.countingTracker to: " + currentCount + " at " + instant + "." );
        }
    }
}
```

The `System.out` object does not necessarily report chronologically. As you can see here, the second event appeared on the console before the first. So follow the `Instant` moments to see true order of events.

```
`Counter` object in thread 16 set this.countingTracker to: 2 at 2021-08-06T16:34:02.460073Z.
`Counter` object in thread 15 set this.countingTracker to: 1 at 2021-08-06T16:34:02.459625Z.
`Counter` object in thread 15 set this.countingTracker to: 3 at 2021-08-06T16:34:07.463863Z.
`Counter` object in thread 16 set this.countingTracker to: 4 at 2021-08-06T16:34:09.463869Z.
`Counter` object in thread 17 set this.countingTracker to: 5 at 2021-08-06T16:34:12.459813Z.
`Counter` object in thread 15 set this.countingTracker to: 6 at 2021-08-06T16:34:16.460429Z.
`Counter` object in thread 16 set this.countingTracker to: 7 at 2021-08-06T16:34:17.463699Z.
`Counter` object in thread 16 set this.countingTracker to: 8 at 2021-08-06T16:34:22.463406Z.
`Counter` object in thread 17 set this.countingTracker to: 9 at 2021-08-06T16:34:23.463713Z.
`Counter` object in thread 15 set this.countingTracker to: 10 at 2021-08-06T16:34:27.463391Z.
`Counter` object in thread 16 set this.countingTracker to: 11 at 2021-08-06T16:34:30.463637Z.
`Counter` object in thread 17 set this.countingTracker to: 12 at 2021-08-06T16:34:32.463385Z.
`Counter` object in thread 17 set this.countingTracker to: 13 at 2021-08-06T16:34:37.463273Z.
`Counter` object in thread 15 set this.countingTracker to: 14 at 2021-08-06T16:34:37.463329Z.
`Counter` object in thread 17 set this.countingTracker to: 15 at 2021-08-06T16:34:42.463201Z.
count = 15
```

You asked:

> I am trying to communicate between two threads

One solution is to replace the `AtomicInteger` object shared by `Runnable` objects across threads with a thread-safe message queue object, as mentioned in [Answer by erickson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68684539/642706).

Comment: Thank you very much ! I ended up declaring a public static attribute in a class and using it for inter-thread communication, I don't know why I hadn't looked at the problem this way