# Producer Consumer using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, consumer, producer

I’m writing a program that implements the Producer Consumer problem in Java using multithreading concepts. Below are few details how I’m supposed to do it:

1)  The main thread should create a buffer with capacity specified as a command line argument. The number of producer and consumer threads are also specified as command line arguments. I’m supposed to assign a unique number to each producer and consumer thread. How do I assign a unique number to producer and consumer threads?

2)  The producer thread operates in an infinite loop. It produces a data item (a string) with the following format: `<producer number>_<data item number>`. For example the 1st data item from thread  number 1 will be 1_1 and second data item  from thread number 3 will be 3_2. How do create data items in such a format?

3)  Then the Producer thread writes an entry into the producer log file (< producer number > “Generated” `<data item>`). Upon writing the log entry, it attempts to insert into the buffer. If insertion is successful, it creates an entry into the log file (`<producer number> <data item>` “Insertion successful”). How do I write such a code?

Below is the Java code I wrote.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class PC2
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
            ArrayList<Integer> queue = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            int size = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            Thread[] prod = new Thread[Integer.parseInt(args[0])];
            Thread[] cons = new Thread[Integer.parseInt(args[1])];

            for(int i=0; i<prod.length; i++)
            {
                    prod[i] = new Thread(new Producer(queue, size));
                    prod[i].start();
            }

            for(int i=0; i<cons.length; i++)
            {
                    cons[i] = new Thread(new Consumer(queue, size));
                    cons[i].start();
                }

    }
}

class Producer extends Thread
{
    private final ArrayList<Integer> queue;
    private final int size;

    public Producer(ArrayList<Integer> queue, int size)
    {
            this.queue = queue;
            this.size = size;
    }

    public void run()
    {
            while(true){
            for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
            {
                    System.out.println("Produced: "+i+" by id " +Thread.currentThread().getId());
try
                    {
                            produce(i);
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                            Logger.getLogger(Producer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                    }
            }}
    }


    public void produce(int i) throws InterruptedException
    {
            while(queue.size() == size)
            {
                    synchronized(queue)
                    {
                            System.out.println("Queue is full "+Thread.currentThread().getName() +" is waiting, size: "+queue.size());
                            queue.wait();
                       }
            }
            synchronized(queue)
            {
                    queue.add(i);
                    queue.notifyAll();
            }
    }
}

class Consumer extends Thread
{
    private final ArrayList<Integer> queue;
    private final int size;

    public Consumer(ArrayList<Integer> queue, int size)
    {
            this.queue = queue;
            this.size = size;
    }

    public void run()
    {
            while(true)
            {
                    try
                    {       System.out.println("Consumed: "+consume());
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                            Logger.getLogger(Consumer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                    }
            }
    }

    public int consume() throws InterruptedException
    {
            while(queue.isEmpty())
            {
                    synchronized(queue)
                    {
                            System.out.println("Queue is empty "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is waiting, size: "+queue.size());
                            queue.wait();
                        }
            }

            synchronized (queue)
            {
                    queue.notifyAll();
                    System.out.println("Consumed by id "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
                    return (Integer) queue.remove(0);

            }
    }
}
```

How can I carry out the above steps?

Answer (score 1):

> I’m supposed to assign a unique number to each producer and consumer
>   thread. How do I assign a unique number to producer and consumer
>   threads?

Add an instance (non-static) variable to the Producer/Consumer classes. When you initialize the new Producer/Consumer Objects, pass in the unique number. You can keep track of what number you're on with an `int counter` in your main class.

> 2) The producer thread operates in an infinite loop. It produces a
>   data item (a string) with the following format: < producer number >_<
>   data item number > . For example the 1st data item from thread number
>   1 will be 1_1 and second data item from thread number 3 will be 3_2.
>   How do create data items in such a format?

Use synchronized methods and/or atomic variables. Look into Java [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

> 3) Then the Producer thread writes an entry into the producer log file
>   (< producer number > “Generated” < data item >). Upon writing the log
>   entry, it attempts to insert into the buffer. If insertion is
>   successful, it creates an entry into the log file (< producer number >
>   < data item > “Insertion successful”). How do I write such a code?

My answer is the same as the previous question: read about Java concurrency. Spend an hour reading about synchronization, locks, and atomic variables and I guarantee you will easily write your program.

Comment: I'm not supposed to use any thread-safe data structures for this program.

Comment: @user2201650 Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006655/are-java-primitive-ints-atomic-by-design-or-by-accident . Consider if you create an "int index" and use it to access your Queue; e.g. "queue.get(index++)". What do you think would happen?

Comment: I'm referring to Jon Skeet's answer. He clearly says operations on primitive types (like int) are atomic in Java. Therefore it's guaranteed that if one thread does queue.get(index++), the new value of index will be immediately visible to all other threads. Therefore two threads will never get the same Object from the queue.

Comment: I'm a beginner to Java programming. So can you please help me out here?

Comment: This isn't a do your homework site. The help I gave you so far is easily enough to solve your problem. Sorry :(

Comment: I'm new to Java programming So I cannot understand that link you gave me :( I wish I get some help here :(

Answer (score 1):

For producer consumer problem best solution is BlockingQueue. I was testing a few things so designed same kind of program now modified it as per your need.

See if it helps.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
public class ThreadingExample {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        BlockingQueue<Message> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Message>(100);
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        exec.execute(new Producer(blockingQueue));
        exec.execute(new Consumer(blockingQueue));
    }

}
class Message{
    private static int count=0;
    int messageId;
    Message(){
        this.messageId=count++;
        System.out.print("message Id"+messageId+" Created ");
    }
}
class Producer implements Runnable{

    private BlockingQueue<Message> blockingQueue;
    Producer(BlockingQueue<Message> blockingQueue){
        this.blockingQueue=blockingQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(!Thread.interrupted()){
            System.out.print("Producer Started");
            try {
                blockingQueue.put(new Message());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Producer Done");
        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable{
    private BlockingQueue<Message> blockingQueue;
    Consumer(BlockingQueue<Message> blockingQueue){
        this.blockingQueue=blockingQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(!Thread.interrupted()){
            System.out.print("Concumer Started");
            try{
                Message message  = blockingQueue.take();
                System.out.print("message Id"+message.messageId+" Consumed ");
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Concumer Done");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is BlockingQueue thread safe? Because I'm not supposed to use any thread safe data structures.

Comment: Can anyone help me out here please? (Sorry if I'm pushing)

Comment: @user2201650 go through this question for your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695426/are-linkedblockingqueues-insert-and-remove-methods-thread-safe

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following which might work for you, except for the buffer condition on 3, which you can add the part of the code by yourself.
Hope this helps.

```
public class Message {

    private String msg;

    public Message(String msg) {
        super();
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getMsg(){
        return msg;
    }
}




import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class Producer implements Runnable {

    private BlockingQueue<Message> queue;
    private boolean run = true;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<Message> queue) {
        super();
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void setRun(boolean val) {
        this.run = val;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        while (run) {
            Message msg = new Message(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "_"+ i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(i * 100);
                queue.put(msg);
                System.out.println("Producer: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" produced and added to the queue: "+msg.getMsg());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
            if(i==10){
                setRun(false);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" stopped");
            }
        }

    }
}



import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class Consumer implements Runnable{

    private BlockingQueue<Message> queue;
    private boolean run = true;

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Message> queue) {
        super();
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void setRun(boolean val){
        this.run = val;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(run){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                Message msg = queue.take();
                System.out.println("Consumer: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"         generated/consumed "+msg.getMsg());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
  }




import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class ProducerConsumerMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out
                .println("please enter the number of producer:consumer:size of the queue in order");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        Thread[] prodThreads = new Thread[scan.nextInt()];
        Thread[] consThreads = new Thread[scan.nextInt()];
        BlockingQueue<Message> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Message>(scan.nextInt());

        for (int i = 0; i < prodThreads.length; i++) {
            prodThreads[i] = new Thread(new Producer(queue), "" + i);
            prodThreads[i].start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < consThreads.length; i++) {
            consThreads[i] = new Thread(new Consumer(queue), "" + i);
            consThreads[i].start();
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below code. You can change the constant values based on the command line arguments. I have tested the code, its working as per your requirement.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class ProducerConsumerProblem {
    public static int CAPACITY = 10; // At a time maximum of 10 tasks can be
                                        // produced.
    public static int PRODUCERS = 2;
    public static int CONSUMERS = 4;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Queue<String> mTasks = new LinkedList<String>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= PRODUCERS; i++) {
            Thread producer = new Thread(new Producer(mTasks));
            producer.setName("Producer " + i);
            producer.start();
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= CONSUMERS; i++) {
            Thread consumer = new Thread(new Consumer(mTasks));
            consumer.setName("Consumer " + i);
            consumer.start();
        }

    }

}

class Producer implements Runnable {

    Queue<String> mSharedTasks;
    int taskCount = 1;

    public Producer(Queue<String> mSharedTasks) {
        super();
        this.mSharedTasks = mSharedTasks;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (mSharedTasks) {
                try {
                    if (mSharedTasks.size() == ProducerConsumerProblem.CAPACITY) {
                        System.out.println("Producer Waiting!!");
                        mSharedTasks.wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            while (mSharedTasks.size() != ProducerConsumerProblem.CAPACITY) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }

                String produceHere = Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + "_Item number_" + taskCount++;

                synchronized (mSharedTasks) {
                    mSharedTasks.add(produceHere);
                    System.out.println(produceHere);
                    if (mSharedTasks.size() == 1) {
                        mSharedTasks.notifyAll(); // Informs consumer that there
                                                    // is something to consume.
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
    Queue<String> mSharedTasks;

    public Consumer(Queue<String> mSharedTasks) {
        super();
        this.mSharedTasks = mSharedTasks;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (mSharedTasks) {
                if (mSharedTasks.isEmpty()) { // Checks whether there is no task
                                                // to consume.
                    try {
                        mSharedTasks.wait(); // Waits for producer to produce!
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
            while (!mSharedTasks.isEmpty()) { // Consumes till task list is
                                                // empty
                try {
                    // Consumer consumes late hence producer has to wait...!
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                synchronized (mSharedTasks) {

                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                            + " consumed " + mSharedTasks.poll());
                    if (mSharedTasks.size() == ProducerConsumerProblem.CAPACITY - 1)
                        mSharedTasks.notifyAll();
                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```