# How to fire event listener from Java thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have thread with Socket inside. When soket receives some data, I need to fire event (using  my sublassed EventObject). Event listeners is added from main thread (to some list?). is this OK?

```
Pseudocode:



public class SocketThread extends Thread{
    private Socket socket;
    private MyEventListener eventListener;

    public SocketThread(Socket socket, MyEventListener eventListener) {
        this.socket=socket;
        this.eventListener=eventListener;
    }

   public void run() {
        get socket input stream...
        get socket output stream...
        when data received, call process(data) 
    }

   void process(data){
     synchronized(this){
        myEvent event=new MyEvent(data);
        eventListener.fireSomeEvent(myEvent );
    }
}


// main thread

ServerSocket serverSocket=new ServerSocket(host,port);
Socket socket= serverSocket.accept();
ClientThread cthr = new SocketThread (sckt,new MyEventListener(){ 
    void fireSomeEvent(MyEvent event){
    //some code
    }
});
```

Comment: I think your solution is generally ok, but I'm thinking you might benefit from implementing the [producer-consumer pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/producer-consumer-pattern). Your socket thread produces messages which are added to a blocking queue, which the other class (the event listener you have presently) grabs from whenever a new message / data is available.

Comment: Should I remove syncronization block?

Comment: Yes, if you do the producer-consumer pattern and you use a blocking queue, you don't need the synchronization block as [the blocking queue's add / take methods are thread safe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2695437/877472).

Answer (score 0):

This seems perfectly fine. As long as you're not changing the `eventListener` there is no concurrency problem that way. But be aware that `fireSomeEvent()` will be ran from the `SocketThread`. If you're doing something that is not thread-safe there, you might (will) encounter problems. So that's where you'll need some sort of synchronization.

Comment: I know events will be fired from the SocketThread. If fired Event is accessing some main thread's data, how to lock that data from fired event? I am firing that event from synchronized block already (should I remove that?)

Comment: That synchronized block is only good for not firing several events concurrently from one socket (which shouldn't happen anyway if your run method fires them without any new threads). I think what you are looking for is synchronizing on the main object (note: object, not thread).

Comment: But it is good for firing several events, using some list, which are added in the same thread (main), inside for loop?